# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 2 models with many to many relation. When I'm trying to find all model1 instances including model2 I have this bug:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value {
  model: Model2,
  required: true,
  where: {
    field: 'value'
  }
}
```

There's my code

```
const result = await Model1.findAll({
      where: {
        data: {[ne]: null},
        include: [{
          model: Model2,
          required: true,
          where: {
            field: value,
          }
        }]
      },
      attributes: ['attribute1', 'attribute2'],
      offset: m,
      limit: n,
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @r9119 is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the "include" option inside of the "where" option in the query.

```
const result = await Model1.findAll({
    where: {data: {[ne]: null}},
    include: [
        {
            model: Model2,
            required: true,
            where: {
                field: value
            }
        }
    ],
    attributes: ['attribute1', 'attribute2'],
    offset: m,
    limit: n
})
```

This should fix it